# How do I deploy a Heroku app with a private repo sucessfully?

Tags: git, heroku

I can't seem to figure this out.  Any ideas why I may be getting the following error?

```
kamilski81:~/Sites/sc:ruby-1.9.3@sc:(master)
$ git push staging master:master
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.89 KiB, done.
Total 16 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.rc
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * source: https://github.com/sc/SC-Models.git (at master)
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * source: https://git_username:git_password@github.com/sc/SC-Models.git (at master)
       You have changed in the Gemfile:
       * sc_models from `https://github.com/sc/SC-Models.git (at master)` to `no specified source`
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:pi-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pi-staging.git'
kamilski81:~/Sites/sc:ruby-1.9.3@sc:(master)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you just need to run bundle install and commit to your branch, then push again.

Comment: Make sure you are commiting all the changes.